Oauth Google Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid
I am trying learn how to logon to the Google and use the API for Calendar, Tasks and Userinfo.  I have used this https://github.com/andygarcia86/python-flask-google-oauth-login as my guide.  It works fine locally but when I tried on my Google Cloud system it gives this errors.  I could really use some help
You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue.
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
Request details: flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
This is my second attempt with using Oauth and it working locally and then running into the same error as above.
I ran it locally and worked and it fails with Google Cloud Platform
Here is my program
# Python standard libraries
import json
import json as json_module
import os
import sqlite3
import sys

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

# Third-party libraries
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from flask_login import (
    LoginManager,
    current_user,
    login_required,
    login_user,
    logout_user,
)
from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient
import requests

# Internal imports
from db import init_db_command
from user import User

# Configuration
with open('./credentials.json', 'r') as file:
    json = json.load(file)
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID     = json['installed']['client_id']
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = json['installed']['client_secret']
GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"

# Flask app setup
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY") or os.urandom(24)

# User session management setup
# https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

# Naive database setup
try:
    init_db_command()
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    # Assume it's already been created
    pass

# OAuth 2 client setup
client = WebApplicationClient(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)

# Flask-Login helper to retrieve a user from our db
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)

# Homepage
@app.route("/")
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return render_template(
            "index.html",
            user_name=current_user.name,
            user_email=current_user.email,
            user_profile_pic=current_user.profile_pic,
        )
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")

# Login
def get_google_provider_cfg():
    return requests.get(GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL).json()

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    # Find out what URL to hit for Google login
    google_provider_cfg = get_google_provider_cfg()
    authorization_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["authorization_endpoint"]

    # Use library to construct the request for Google login and provide
    # scopes that let you retrieve user's profile from Google
    request_uri = client.prepare_request_uri(
        authorization_endpoint,
        redirect_uri=request.base_url + "/callback",
        scope=["openid", "email", "profile"],
    )

    return redirect(request_uri)

# Login Callback
@app.route("/login/callback")
def callback():
    # Get authorization code Google sent back to you
    code = request.args.get("code")

    result = "<p>code: " + code + "</p>"

    google_provider_cfg = get_google_provider_cfg()
    token_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["token_endpoint"]

    # Prepare and send a request to get tokens! Yay tokens!
    token_url, headers, body = client.prepare_token_request(
        token_endpoint,
        authorization_response=request.url,
        redirect_url=request.base_url,
        code=code,
    )
    token_response = requests.post(
        token_url,
        headers=headers,
        data=body,
        auth=(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET),
    )

    # Parse the tokens!
    #lient.parse_request_body_response(json.dumps(token_response.json()))
    client.parse_request_body_response(json_module.dumps(token_response.json()))
    
    # Now that you have tokens (yay) let's find and hit the URL
    # from Google that gives you the user's profile information,
    # including their Google profile image and email
    userinfo_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["userinfo_endpoint"]
    uri, headers, body = client.add_token(userinfo_endpoint)
    userinfo_response = requests.get(uri, headers=headers, data=body)

    result = result + "<p>token_response: " + token_response.text + "</p>"

    # return result

    # You want to make sure their email is verified.
    # The user authenticated with Google, authorized your
    # app, and now you've verified their email through Google!
    if userinfo_response.json().get("email_verified"):
        unique_id = userinfo_response.json()["sub"]
        users_email = userinfo_response.json()["email"]
        picture = userinfo_response.json()["picture"]
        users_name = userinfo_response.json()["given_name"]
    else:
        return "User email not available or not verified by Google.", 400

    # Create a user in your db with the information provided
    # by Google
    user = User(id_=unique_id, name=users_name, email=users_email, profile_pic=picture)

    # Doesn't exist? Add it to the database.
    if not User.get(unique_id):
        User.create(unique_id, users_name, users_email, picture)

    # Begin user session by logging the user in
    login_user(user)

    # Send user back to homepage
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

# Logout
@app.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc", port=5000)

type here


